# How to change file extensions in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I feel like this must be simple, but I can't find the answer.  I'm saving a bunch of csv files using vba and would like to change all the file extensions from .csv to .txt to import into another program (Revit) which only recognizes the .txt extension.  Is this possible?  Here is the command I'm using.

```
    For I = 1 To WS_Count

        path = CurDir() + "\" + ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name

        Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name).Select
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

        Name path As ("path" + ".txt")

     Next I
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You don't even need to open the files to rename them.

```
Sub M_snb()
  name "G:\OF\example.csv" As "G:\OF\example.txt"
end sub
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still having a little trouble.  I'm getting a "file not found" error.  Would you mind taking a peak at my code?  I added it above.

Comment: Nevermind.  Got it.  You can just add .txt to the file name.  Will update the thread.

Comment: this only works if you have enabled file extensions (which are disabled by default in windows 10)

Answer (score 1):

You should change

```
FileFormat:=xlCSV
```

to

```
FileFormat:=xlTextWindows
```

See

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx

or

The xlFileFormat enumeration (Excel) on MSDN

Comment: Thanks but that won't work for what I'm trying to do.  I still the the file to be formatted as comma separated values, but want the extension to be txt.  xlTextWindows uses a different delimiter other than commas.  Looks like tabs.  Snb's suggestion is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it.  You can just ad  txt to the file name, even if it is in the CSV format.

```
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
         For I = 1 To WS_Count

        path = CurDir() + "\" + ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name + ".txt"

        Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name).Select
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False


        Debug.Print (test)
        Debug.Print (path)

     Next I
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this. It will get the file from the specified directory from your system and will return the converted file from CSV to Text.

```
Sub changeExt()

strDir = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\xyz"    'Your file directory

With CreateObject("wscript.shell")

     .currentdirectory = strDir

     .Run "%comspec% /c ren *.csv *.txt", 0, True

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.